# How to avoid checkout of sources on master node with jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to define my builds using the Jenkins 2 pipeline feature and I want this configuration to be loaded from sources in a `Jenkinsfile`.
However I don't want to clutter my `master` node with workspace.

Ideally, I could specify that a pipeline job is meant to be run a given node type but that doesn't seems possible.

I see 2 alternatives:

- use a dedicated repository where the jenkins job configuration is stored.
- use a cleaver git checkout strategy (shallow + sparse).

Did I miss something? What would be the best practice ?

Comment: Good question. I was very surprised to watch the jenkins master to checkout the whole 500 MB repository of our software project just to read the Jenkinsfile in it. It does not make sense to have this checkout on the master since all builds are run on differing slaves that checkout the whole thing again...

Answer (score 2):

There's a Jenkins issue that claims this is now fixed, and only the Jenkinsfile itself needs to be checked out on the master: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273

(It isn't working for me at the moment though.)

Answer (score -1):

I think your can use Jenkinsfile.  But avoid to use step 'git checkout'
Workspace are not acceptable from jenkins web interface. So you can use jenkinsfile to manage your builds.

Comment: I don't get it. How do I avoid the step "git checkout" ?

Comment: I think me too. Your just do not add 'git checkout' at your Jenkins file. and your can do all stages at your slaves using sh command

Comment: That won't work as Jenkinsfile *has to* be checked out on the master to be read (and then execute the content). When you configure your job ou have to specify a scm repository where the Jenkinsfile stay. But there is no option to control where this will be done.